# Replace a variable with stdin?

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, scripting, terminal

I want to loop over some values and I know I can simply use a for loop but is there any other way that I can replace a variable value in a command at the end of the command?

Somewhat like

`echo 11"$p" < 8  #toprint 118`

`echo 11"$p" < 9  #toprint 119`

`echo 11"$p" < a  #toprint 11a`

I want to be able to replace certain variables with my value but at the end of the command.  I know there are multiple ways to do this so I'm not asking for other ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
( read p && echo "11$p" ) <<<8
```

or

```
{ read p && echo "11$p"; } <<<8
```

if the variable is to keep its value after the command.

The `<<<` is a *here-string redirection*. It redirects a single string into a command or utility. Here, we use it to send the digit into the subshell or compound command. This compound command reads the value, then prints it as part of a string.

You can't use `<8` as that would try to read from a *file* called `8`.

Comment: Thanks man looking exactly for this. Can you please help explain it as well? What is <<< for and what purpose do () serve here?

Comment: @trying2learn See updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

If your values are in an array, no need to loop over them, just do:

```
values=(8 9 a)
printf '11%s\n' "${values[@]}"
```

Same if they are in different variables:

```
a=8 b=9 c=a
printf '11%s\n' "$a" "$b" "$c"
```

If the input comes from stdin, you can use `xargs`:

```
xargs printf '11%s\n' << EOF
8 "9"
'a'
EOF
```

(above showing different kinds of quoting or argument delimiter supported by `xargs`).

Or use things like:

```
sed 's/^/11/' << EOF
8
9
a
EOF
```

or

```
awk '{print "11" $0}' << EOF
8
9
a
EOF
```

Generally, [in shell scripting, you don't want to write explicit *loops*](/q/169716). The *looping* is done by those text utilities that process their input one line at a time or one argument at a time.